# Benchmarks similar to TPC-H and TPC-DS

Tags: database, bigdata, benchmarking, join, tpc

What are some of the common benchmarks other than `TPC-H` and `TPC-DS`, that involve many large `fact tables` and multiple `joins` over them ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this question is pertinent to Stackoverflow, but I, too, was once stuck by this problem.

I don't know what is you purpose for such a benchmark dataset and how "large" you expect it to be, but [Mondial](https://www.dbis.informatik.uni-goettingen.de/Mondial/) is a great open relation dataset that I found useful.

You can also find many other relational dataset in [here](https://relational.fit.cvut.cz/).